# Python reads and processes tar files fine but not tar.gz files?

Tags: python, tar, gzip

Working on a code to process archives
Here is a snippet of what I have:

The line where things change is here:

```
tar = tarfile.open(tarName, 'r')
```

It works when I input a regular tar file like above but when I try to do it with tar.gz the x.read() line returns null for some reason...Is there a difference in file extraction between tar and tar.gz?

```
tar = tarfile.open(tarName, 'r:gz')

directory = directoryname+'/'
if not os.path.exists(directory) and not (param1 == 2):
    os.makedirs(directory)

start = time.time()
numTotal = 0;
numFound = 0;

#case 1: look for string anywhere
if (param2 == 0):

    for currentFile in tar:
        numTotal+=1;
        x=tar.extractfile(currentFile)

        if stringCheck in x.read():

          numFound +=1

          if (param1 == 2):
        continue

          new = open(directory + ntpath.basename(currentFile.name), 'w');
          x.seek(0,0)
          new.write( x.read() )
          new.close()
          if (param1 == 1):
```

Output for

```
file newTarGz.tar.gz
```

is
   newTarGz.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Thu Jun 12 11:02:55 2014, from Unix

Also, the continue error was due to copypasting over to stack overflow- fixed

Edit: Working on Cygwin if that makes any difference

Comment: Can we assume you verified the tar.gz file is valid by opening it with another utility?

Comment: Also, you have an indentation problem on the `continue` line.

Comment: Also also, and I am unfamiliar with the library so I am just spit balling here, is it possible that the first `currentFile in tar` is actually a directory or something that does not respond well to the `x=tar.extractfile(currentFile)` or `x.read()` methods?

Comment: Do a `tar -tf <filename>` to ensure that the file is valid

Comment: When I did the tar -tf filename thing,it printed out all the file names...also WHen I try to "un-gz" the file but it won't actually uncompress it...?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! The extractions are different. That's because the compression of files, in the first place is different. A .tar file is normally compressed with transparent tar compression, whereas tar.gz file is compressed with "gzip" compression. There are other compressions, which the tarfile module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) supports i.e., .bz2(uses bzip2 compression), .tar.Z, etc. For more details refer to official tarfile documentation.